# What's the protocol to safely measure voltages in an open residential junction box?

Tags: wiring, safety

If I have a box at home with some wires that need tracing or identifying or debugging, and I want to measure voltages between them, I do it when nobody is home so I don't have bare energized wires sticking out of a box with people around while I run up and down to the breaker.

What is the protocol for an electrician to do this in a customer's home?   Do you have to have two people, one to guard the open box while the other goes to turn on the breaker?   Or do you use lever nuts or similar that insulate the bare wire ends while allowing reliable meter probe insertion?   Is there an accepted protocol for this?   I don't have pets but is it normal for an electrician to ask customers to put their pets in a closed room while working?

Comment: I do my electrical work when somebody else is around to call 911 in case I really mess up...

Comment: I do mine at home when the wife is there so I don't have to run back and forth to the breaker. She sits there and reads and flips things off/on at my request. Especially handy for multi-floor work or if I'm in the crawl space. I'll use my cell phone & a blutooth headset to ensure we communicate clearly.

Comment: @FreeMan  And what happens if she just happens to be pissed at you??? :-)

Comment: She's the queen of the castle, @JACK, what does she have to be PO'd about?

Comment: Maybe about having to hang around in the basement while you mess around with all your little wires?  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have always worked by myself and have always covered the bare ends with wire nuts when going back and forth to the breaker. I've had dogs and cats open doors and kids coming home unexpectedly so I never assume I'll be alone the whole time. I also will tag and tape breakers.

Answer (score 6):

Pets and little kids (all ages for receptacles near the floor, somewhat older for light switches, etc.) need to be kept out of the way. Beyond that, shouldn't really be an issue. Pets and little kids should be out of the way with any workers (carpenter, plumber, etc.) to avoid getting in the way and avoid sharp/dangerous tools, even when there is no dangerous infrastructure (bare wires) involved.

So in residential work, this is just not a big deal.

That being said, there is a concept of a *lockout*. This is to prevent someone at the breaker turning it on, not realizing there is work being done. The basic idea is that if you need to do work with power *off* and the shutoff is not within visual range (generally speaking, the same room) then you turn off the breaker (or disconnect/shutoff switch) and put on a physical tag that prevents turning it back on without removing or breaking the tag. That does not, of course, prevent malicious conduct. But it prevents, for example, someone finding a receptacle doesn't work and who doesn't know the electrician is working on the circuit, from going to the panel, seeing the breaker off and turning it back on, zapping the electrician who is working on a different receptacle on the same circuit in a different room.

Even with lockouts, in a typical home this is not a big deal because there are not many people around and *most* people who walk in the door would at least notice the electrician's truck outside and ask questions before blindly resetting breakers.

But in an apartment building, office building, factory, etc. lockouts are definitely a required *and critically important* thing.

Comment: Right, I've seen lockouts in use at work and I agree that in a home you have to give the residents some credence to not turn a breaker on without asking you while you're working.   I'm concerned about the opposite.  Kids and pets are out of sight.  You lay out some wires and go turn it on and HOPE that while you're walking back the kids and pets don't reappear or adult doesn't suddenly want a sweater, enter the room and without looking reach for the switch that is now a bunch of open energized wires?

Comment: regarding lockouts, I heard an anecdote once where an asbestos removal guy told the homeowner that yes, it was silly he had to put up all these sheets and warning signs since the homeowner knows the danger is there - and then the plumber showed up at the same time! so, yeah, it may be usually not required, but sometimes it is

Answer (score -1):

In some countries the protocol is named "5 safety rules".

Here is a wikipedia entry about this subject for Europe.

An english language entry seems to be missing, so translate.google is used (translation needs some seconds):

https://de-m-wikipedia-org.translate.goog/wiki/F%C3%BCnf_Sicherheitsregeln?_x_tr_sl=de&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US

Comment: And in Australia I have seen plastic lockout padlocks, with a picture of the electrician on them.